# Matlab arrays coverting

Tags: c#, .net, matlab

I have a project from university, where I have to make a `.net` assembly using Matlab.

How to put this type of array

```
double [] A = {-4.52359871943070, 0.848593515459917, 0.291613401331876 };
```

as an argument of a function that accepts `MWArray`

Comment: Create a MWNumericArray with your double[] array (https://www.mathworks.com/help/dotnetbuilder/MWArrayAPI/html/M_MathWorks_MATLAB_NET_Arrays_MWNumericArray__ctor_7.htm) and pass this as argument.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I am doing this                                             
MWArray[] itemParams = { -4.52359871943070,   0.848593515459917,   0.291613401331876}; and it is not working, because it says that can not covert MWarray [] to MWarray

Comment: You said in your question you need an `MWArray`. So why do you try to create a `MWArray[]` now? Perhaps double-check what you really want/need and update the question accordingly...

Comment: Because it gives me an error if I make the array of a type MWarray, and if it is declared of type MWarray []  it is ok, but then in the function, it gives an error.

Comment: Because the function wants an `MWArray` and not an `MWArray[]`, if i understand your explanations correctly. See my first comment again.

Comment: Yes, but when I declare the array this way           MWArray itemParams = { -4.52359871943070,   0.848593515459917,   0.291613401331876};  visual studio gives an error

Comment: Once more, look at my fist comment, and please pay attention when reading it and follow the link to the documentation i gave...

Comment: It looks to me as if you are struggling and stuck because of lacking basic C# understanding/skills. Why did the university assign this project to you instead of assigning it to someone who has a solid understanding of C#?

Comment: If I knew how to do it I  wouldn't make a post here. If you can give me a solution please just write it down straight if no just don't answer. I tried different ways of declaring the array but always says that can't convert it to MWArray. From the link, you provided I can't understand anything. There is maybe a way to cast different types, but I am new to Matlab and I have no idea what can be done and what not, but still I need to make it work.

Comment: If you are new to MatLab, if you can't understand MatLab.NET's API documentation, if you are struggling with basic C# concepts, and if you didn't even try creating an MWNumericArray as i said, why did you even got assigned to the project? To be frank and direct, you are woefully unequipped to execute the project. The solution here is to talk to your university project lead, and sort out this conundrum. I don't know what happened between the uni and you when you agreed to make this project despite lacking the basic knowledge to actually do it, but something went horribly wrong

Comment: I thought people here make their accounts to help others, not to get involved in their lives. But still, thank you for not helping me, but still spending your time.

Comment: My apologies for overstepping a line. The technical solution to your coding problem is in my first comment. Do with it as you please...